# $\mathfrak{u}(2)=\{S \in Mat(n,\mathbb{C}) | S^{\dagger}=-S \}$ generators

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, change-of-basis

I am calculating the generators of the algebra

$$\mathfrak{u}(2)=\{S \in Mat(n,\mathbb{C}) | S^{\dagger}=-S \}$$
   $$ S=\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} + i\,b_{11} & a_{12} + i\,b_{12} \\ 
     a_{21} + i\,b_{21} & a_{22} + i\,b_{22}
  \end{pmatrix} \quad
  (a_{ii},b_{ii} \in \mathbb{R})$$

$$ \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} - i\,b_{11} & a_{21} - i\,b_{21} \\ 
     a_{12} - i\,b_{12} & a_{22} - i\,b_{22}
  \end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} -a_{11} - i\,b_{11} & -a_{12} - i\,b_{12} \\ 
     -a_{21} - i\,b_{21} & -a_{22} - i\,b_{22}
  \end{pmatrix} \quad
  $$
$$S=A+iB$$
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 
     1 & 0 
  \end{pmatrix} \,\,\,\,\,\, B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 
     1 & 1 
  \end{pmatrix}  $$

Considering $\sigma_i$ the [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices), it is known that an algebra is:

$$
\left(\ T^{1}, \ T^{2}, \ T^{3}, \ T^{4} \ \right) = \left(\ \frac{1}{2} \sigma_{1}, \ \frac{1}{2} \sigma_{2}, \ \frac{1}{2} \sigma_{3}, \ \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{I} \ \right) 
$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{4}T^{i}= \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1-i \\ 
     1+i & 0 
  \end{pmatrix}$$

Did I make a miscalculations? If my derivation is right what is the relationship between the two?

Comment: What is $\;T\;$ , what is $\;\sigma\;$ ...? Why do you think $\;S\;$ in $\;M_2(\Bbb C\;$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply transcribed the solution for the generic Lie algebra element wrong; solving the defining constraint yields, by inspection, 
$$S= a_{21}\begin{pmatrix} 0& -1 \\ 
     1 &0
  \end{pmatrix} +i  \begin{pmatrix}  b_{11} &  b_{12} \\ 
     b_{12} & b_{22}
  \end{pmatrix} \\
 = -ia_{21} ~ \sigma_{2} +i\left ( b_{12}~\sigma_{1} +  \frac{b_{11}-b_{22} }{2} ~\sigma_{3} + \frac{b_{11}+b_{22}}{2} ~\mathbb{I} \right) .
$$